# .net why cannot convert from int[] to object[]

Tags: .net, object, boxing

I have the following method

```
private void AM(object[] x)
{
}
```

When we call it like this:

```
int[] x = new int[1];
AM(x);
```

We get a compilation error, something like "invalid arguments", "cannot convert from int[] to object[]".

But, if we have an argument (object y), we can have input int as input parameter.

My question is: why Microsoft design them in different ways?

Comment: Why have you prototyped the function thusly? Is this something you have written and can change?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When you pass an `int` (a value type) into a method with an `object` (a reference type) parameter, a new object is created on the heap and the value of the `int` is copied into it. A reference to the object (the boxed `int`) is then given passed into the method parameter.

`int[]` and `object[]` are both arrays, but they have very different element types.  As arrays, they are both reference types, and so a method taking an `object[]` parameter is expecting a reference to an array of objects.  A reference to an array of ints is very different.

Because `int` is a value type, there's no simple way to turn a reference to `int[]` into a reference to `object[]` without iterating over the whole `int[]` and boxing each element.  That could be an expensive operation in terms of time and memory, and the compiler is not going to do it for you automatically.

Answer (score 5):

Only arrays of reference types may be assigned to arrays of other reference types (like Object). Since int is a value type, you can't do this.

This is called [Array Covariance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664572%28v=VS.71%29.aspx)

> Array covariance specifically does not extend to arrays of
>   value-types. For example, no conversion exists that permits an int[]
>   to be treated as an object[].

Answer (score 2):

An array of objects is a completely different animal when compared to an array of int (as you can see with the cast error you get). However, both object[] and int[] are objects, so you can 
cast them both to their *primal* type (as in primitive) which is the object.